# Linking to external site from Chrome single app kiosk mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

We are using single app kiosk mode to keep a page from been closed. However, we cannot link to external sites. Any idea how to link to other sites?

Answer (score 1):

To display external content inside a Chrome app, you need a [`<webview>`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview).